# Problema persistente en Android studio : Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityCompat' ' Crashlytics' ' Fabric'

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un serio problema el cual no me deja seguir con mi proyecto, resulta que la semana pasada compile mi ultima versión (1.1.6) por los momentos de mi proyecto, lo lance y todo marcha bien con los dispositivos, fabric y firebase van de maravilla informandome, deje de abrir el proyecto en android desde hace 4 días después del lanzamiento de la versión, y hoy que lo vuelvo a abrir para bien, mejorar algunas cosas me ha dado la sorpresa android studio que me marca:

> ```
> Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityCompat'
> Cannot resolve symbol 'Crashlytics'
> Cannot resolve symbol 'Fabric'
> ```

Intente en 'Invalidate cache & restar' No resolvió.
Probe con 'Clean projec' también con 'Rebuild' y sigue sin poder resolverse, intente compilar mi proyecto en el emulador y no me lanzo ningún error, lo volvi a compilar en mi Android via USB y tampoco me dio error, sin embargo en android studio persiste marcando que no se puede resolver el símbolo...

Este es el archivo build.gradle (app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.cinemovil.xploit"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.1.jar')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Y este es el otro build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //google()
        //maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer resolví el problema eliminando la carpeta `.idea`

Probe este metodo:

> 1. Borrar la carpeta .idea
> 2. Cerrar y volver a abrir el proyecto.
> 3. File -> Sincronizar proyecto con archivos Gradle.

que comentaron en SO en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50466179/9747316

Abrí nuevamente el proyecto, sincronice el proyecto con los archivos `gradle` y se esfumo el error en `Android Studio`.

Comment: Hola Luis, agrega siempre el error completo que se muestra. ¿Donde viste que eliminando .idea se resuelve?

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, Estuve leyendo y leyendo en varios lugares, pero ninguno me daba solución, simplemente en Android studio me subrayaba "rojo" lo comentado anteriormente en la pregunta, pero no me daba errores al compilar ni nada. Trate todos los métodos de clear project, invalidate cache, y nada, probe eliminando la carpeta .idea como lo comento el usuario -Muhamed Krasniqi- y resultó.

Comment: Me parece que algún archivo se corrompió  o se des configuro, al eliminar .idea y volver a entrar a android studio se crea nuevamente con la configuración default. Modifiqué un poco tu respuesta, cuando puedas marcala como solución Luis!, saludos.

Comment: Ninguna respuesta funcionó en mi caso. :(